# Remote devices unable to connect to a new Arch install

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I seem to have got something very wrong with my network setup, is anyone able to see what I have done wrong from this info?

seemingly its possible to ssh to the machine

however, any  other service seems to have issues..  if  anyone can point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated! thanks

```
mike@mike-arch:~|⇒  nc -l -p 1234

mike@mike-arch:~|⇒  nc -zvw10 192.168.8.103 1234
Warning: Host 192.168.8.103 isn't authoritative! (direct lookup mismatch)
  192.168.8.103 -> mike-arch  BUT  mike-arch -> 127.0.0.1
192.168.8.103 1234 (search-agent): Connection refused
```

/etc/hosts

```
mike@mike-arch:~|⇒  cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       mike-arch
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             mike-arch
```

iptables

```
mike@mike-arch:~|⇒  sudo iptables -L                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[sudo] password for mike:                                                                                                                    
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                                                  
target     prot opt source               destination  

LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootpc
```

Answer (score -1):

In your hosts file you have set your hostname with the loopback address, instead of the actual IP address.

Your /etc/hosts file should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
127.0.1.1   mike-arch
```

Comment: That still assigns the hostname to a  loopback address.